# SQL, Inner join, 2 tables and 2 columns information

Tags: sql

I 'd like to check if i'm using the best method about such a case:

2 Tables: 
First table : information about invoice, with notably 2 columns : 
=> ID responsible 1 (columns id_user1) and ID responsable 2 (columns id_user2)
Table : tb_invoice

Second Table : id, name of all responsables.
Table : tb_users (columns : id_user, name ...)

And for getting information about the 2 responsables on the invoice, I do the link like this :

```
select 
 t1.*,
 tu1.name as responsable_1,
 tu2.name as responsable_2
from 
 tb_invoice t1
 inner join tb_users tu1 on tu1.id_user=t1.id_user1
 inner join tb_users tu2 on tu2.id_user=t1.id_user2
where 
 t1.num = 123456
```

Is there another solution and better ?
Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Comment: Alias `t1` confusion.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text,

Comment: Apart from your issues with the alias, this is a pretty solid approach

Comment: The query looks good. As to the table design: This suggests that there will never be more than two responsibles and that there may be a difference in status between a responsible1 and a responsible2. Looks fine to me. Whether a separate responsibles table instead would be better or worse depends.

Comment: What if there's only one responsable for an invoice? I'd consider `LEFT JOIN`s - just in case.

Comment: @JohnHC: actually `select foo x from foo` **is** valid standard SQL - but I do agree that fabrice most probably didn't mean to write that

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your aliases confusion (edited your question) and your query is a pretty good solution

```
select 
 t1.id,
 tu1.name as responsable_1,
 tu2.name as responsable_2
from 
 tb_invoice t1
 inner join tb_users tu1 on tu1.id_user=t1.id_user1
 inner join tb_users tu2 on tu2.id_user=t1.id_user2
where 
 t1.num = 123456
```

If one invoice can have only one (or no) responsable so it is recommended to use **Left Join** instead of **Inner Join**